# How can i put this query into a stored procedure in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select guest.guestid, guest.firstname,guesttype,reservation.reservationid, rental.checkindate, rental.checkoutdate, reservation.numberofnights

from guest
inner JOIN rental ON rental.guestid = guest.guestid

inner JOIN reservation ON rental.reservationid = reservation.reservationid

where guest.guestid = 1111;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure_name(arg1 data_type, ...) AS
BEGIN
  [Your query]
END procedure_name;
```